# Frequency & amplitue

Tags: frequency, wave, amplitude

I have a sql table which contains 2 columns:

[image]

How to calculate the frequency of the highest amplitude wave ?
(Each wave is of fixed frequency).
Thank you

Comment: Is the second column the amplitude?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

`select 1/Time as frequency from <table> order by amplitude desc limit 1`

Comment: This gives a number, which is almost certainly wrong. The time shown is periodic (1.64E-08 step) which means that the data represents a time series.